# Reloading changes previously made in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

Im manually swapping pairs of letters in a string, it works only once, if i try to change a second pair, the previously swapped pair will be swapped back, how can i reload the string with the previously made swaps?

Here's the code that i have:

```
 <?php

        function manual($letter1, $letter2, $text) {
            $changed = str_split($text);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count( $changed); $i++) {
                if ( $changed[$i] == $letter1) {
                     $changed[$i] = $letter2;
                } elseif ( $changed[$i] == $letter2) {
                     $changed[$i] = $letter1;
                }
            }
            return  $changed;
        }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
            <p>Letra 1: <input type="text" name="firstletter" /></p>
            <p>Letra 2: <input type="text" name="secondletter" /></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['firstletter']) && isset($_POST['secondletter'])) {
    $ch = $_POST['firstletter'];
    echo $ch . "<br />";
    $ch2 = $_POST['secondletter'];
    echo $ch2;
    $final = manual($ch, $ch2, $final);
    echo "<pre><br />" . implode("", $final) . "</pre>";
}
    ?>
```

***The whole code of the program is:***

```
        <?php

        function manual($letter1, $letter2, $text) {
            $changed = str_split($text);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count( $changed); $i++) {
                if ( $changed[$i] == $letter1) {
                     $changed[$i] = $letter2;
                } elseif ( $changed[$i] == $letter2) {
                     $changed[$i] = $letter1;
                }
            }
            return  $changed;
        }

        $reference = file_get_contents('/textfiles/reference_file.txt', true);
        $encrypted = file_get_contents('/textfiles/encrypted_file.txt', true);

        $azreference = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $reference);
        $azencrypted = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $encrypted);

        $refarray1 = array_count_values(str_split($azreference, '1'));
        $refarray2 = array_count_values(str_split($azencrypted, '1'));
        $replacement = array();

        foreach ($refarray1 as $key => $val) {
            foreach ($refarray2 as $key2 => $val2) {
                if ($val == $val2) {
                    $replacement[$key2] = $key;
                }
            }
        }

        $final = strtr($encrypted, $replacement);
        echo "<pre>" . $final . "</pre>";
        echo "<br />";
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <p>Letra 1: <input type="text" name="firstletter" /></p>
            <p>Letra 2: <input type="text" name="secondletter" /></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

 <?php
            if (isset($_POST['firstletter']) && isset($_POST['secondletter'])) {
                $ch = $_POST['firstletter'];
                $ch2 = $_POST['secondletter'];
                if (file_exists('C:/xampp/htdocs/ictfinal/file.txt')) {
                    $finalfile = 'file.txt';
                    $handle = fopen($finalfile, 'r+') or die('Cannot open file:  ' . $my_file);
                    $file1 = file_get_contents('/file.txt', true);
                    $final = manual($ch, $ch2, $file1);

                    $data = implode("", $final);
                    fwrite($handle, $data);
                } else {
                    $final = manual($ch, $ch2, $final);
                    $finalfile = 'file.txt';
                    $handle = fopen($finalfile, 'w+') or die('Cannot open file:  ' . $my_file);
                    $data = implode("", $final);
                    file_put_contents('C:/xampp/htdocs/ictfinal/file.txt', $data);
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Can you share any example what you want to do exactly?

Comment: In addition to an example, mind explaining where `$final` is being initialized at the bottom? It's undeclared prior to your using it in the manual function.

Comment: @Amit Rajpuj

Example

String:  xyza
Swap1 (y and x): yxza
Swap2 (z and a): xyaz    , xy are swapped to the original state, wich i dont want to happen

Comment: @allejo $final is inicialized before this code, ill edit the question with the whole code

Comment: Could you clarify your example a bit more and maybe update the code samples with more generic code (i.e. only what is relevant to your question)? We'd be able to help you better that way instead of wondering/guessing what something like `/textfiles/reference_file.txt` contains.

Comment: The text files contain a Text(reference_file), and a direct letter swap encription for that text(encrypted_file). 
What im doing is counting the number of ocurrences for each letter in both files, then run the string containing the entire encrypted text that i took from the encrypted text file and swap letters with letters with the same number of ocurrences, as, some letters have the same number of ocurrences(i.e a:55 ocurrences and o:55 ocurrences), i want to manually swap letters

Comment: Ok, i managed to fix it, saving the string into a file, and looping it like:

    `if (file_exists($filename)) {
       //do something using the file
    } else {
       //do something and save it as a file
    }`